# jQuery on click fadeToggle submenu

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to create links that open their submenus on click. At the moment, the script just opens all the submenus and not the ones assigned to that specific link.

HTML

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a class="menu">Category A</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a href="#">Item A</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item B</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="menu">Category B</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a href="#">Item C</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item D</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

jQuery

```
$("nav ul li").click(function() {
    var submenu = $(this).find('.submenu');
    $('.submenu').not(submenu).fadeToggle().removeClass('opened');
    submenu.addClass('opened').fadeToggle();
});
```

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j44163w9/2/)

If Category A is clicked, I want it to show only the Item A and Item B. (At the moment it displays all items from all categories)
Then if Category B is clicked, I want it to hide the Category A and only show the currently open category.

Comment: See my answer for a clean approach. Besides this could completely done with CSS without any jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just do:

```
$(".menu").on('click', function() {
  var submenu = $(this).next('.submenu');
  if($('.thisul').find('.submenu') != $(this)){
      $('.thisul').find('.submenu').fadeOut();
  }
  submenu.fadeToggle();
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j44163w9/4/

and just add class

```
<nav>
  <ul class="thisul">...
   ...
```

Comment: Same as above: I guess I wasn't clear enough in what I want. Basically, now both of them can be opened simultaneously. I want it to be so if Category A is open and you click Category B, the Category A gets closed.

Comment: Thank you. That works perfectly. Instead of adding that class to the ul, I used $('nav ul') and that seems to work the same. :)

Answer (score 0):

Fix: 
Check for the anchor link's next sibling called `.submenu`, then use that as a target to fade toggle the menu.

### JQuery:

```
$("nav ul li a").click(function() {
    var $submenu = $(this).next(".submenu").not(".opened");
    $(".submenu.opened").fadeOut().removeClass("opened");
    $submenu.fadeIn().addClass("opened");
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ov0Lapx4/1/

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear enough in what I want. Basically, now both of them can be opened simultaneously. I want it to be so if Category A is open and you click Category B, the Category A gets closed.

Answer (score 0):

### a clean way, without race condition for the animations

#### html

```
<nav>
    <ul class="container">
        <li>
            <a class="menu">Category A</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a href="#">Item A</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item B</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <!-- ... -->
    </ul>
</nav>
```

#### js

```
$(".container .menu").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $this = $(this);
    var $menu = $this.parent();    
    var $container = $this.closest("ul.container");

    $container.find('ul').removeClass('opened').fadeOut('fast', function() {
        var $submenu = $menu.find('.submenu');
        $submenu.fadeIn('fast').addClass('opened');
    });    
});
```

> [Refer to this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j44163w9/8/)
>
> Keep in mind this could me done completely with CSS without any javascript